# Problema con Django. TemplateDoesNotExist at /

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls

Al parecer tengo problemas con el servidor de Django, cuando voy a refrescar la ventana en mi navegador y  ver el resultado de mi templete creado en un archivo index.html. Me muestra lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me dice que no existe mi template

Paso a mostrarles mi organizacion de archivos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y los códigos que eh modificado y eh agregado en los archivos de Django:

Codigo de mi archivo "settings.py" (TEMPLATES)

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},]
```

Codigo de mi archivo "urls.py"

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
     path('', views.index, name='index'),
     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Codigo de mi archivo "views.py"

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return render(request,'index.html',{
       #contexto
    })
```

Una captura de lo que pasa en mi terminal cuando actualizo mi navegador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me da errores en los archivos que ni siquiera los abrí ni modifique.

Espero que puedan echarme una mano y aver ganado esta experiencia.

Comment: por lo que parece no tienes creada la carpeta templates con el archivo index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ya encontre la solucion.**

Por error abría creado la carpeta "templates" dentro de la carpeta CityTours donde estan los archivos que modificamos. Por lo que no es correcto crearlo en ese nivel.

**Lo correcto**
Era crearlo al nivel donde se encuentra el archivo "manage.py"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]